# sip client for android device with wired conenction

Tags: android, sip

Can you please name some SIP Client application for wired android device. By default all sip client takes either WiFi or Data network. My Device is having Ethernet connection.

Comment: what kind of wired device you are using ?

Comment: We Have our own tablet with only Ethernet port, no WiFi or data network in it.

Comment: CSipSimple, Sipdroid, Linphone.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/checkout

You can use this for sip in android.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong: regardless of the physical layer (WiFi, 3G/LTE or Ethernet) (almost) any client SIP application should work.